# Is this measure theory question suitable for MO?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question, math-stackexchange

A moderator at Mathematics StackExchange asks if this question would be suitable for migration to MO: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331258/using-a-sequence-of-measures-to-create-simple-functions-which-approximate-the-ra I said that I wasn't sure but would put it up for discussion at meta. (To me the level seems reasonable, but others may feel differently.)

Comment: Since so far there have been no howls of protest, I assume that the question would be all right. I'll wait a little longer, and if the pattern continues I'll have the question migrated, with a link to this meta post.

Comment: It seems that the migration from MSE to MO was rejected: http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1331258/revisions Why was that? If people voted it to be off-topic here, could it at least be reopened at MSE?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta The OP deleted the question at MO, after coming to the conclusion that it wasn't sensible after all (this was in response to a pertinent comment by an MO user). So it seems this situation doesn't need to be rescued.